# docker - updating requirements.pip

Tags: docker

Suppose you have many packages listed in your requirements.pip

Now you want to add another package to the `requirements.pip` .

When you do `docker-compose build`, it will try to install every package in the `requirements.pip` again and takes very long time.

Is there a way to avoid that?

- edit

I'm pasting relevant parts

```
COPY ./momsite/requirements.pip /requirements.pip
RUN /virtualenvs/littlehome/bin/pip install -r /requirements.pip

COPY . /app
```

Comment: Docker-compose doesnt build the image. Its from Dockerfile you should paste it here

Comment: @MazelTov updated the OP

Comment: Dockerfile uses cache for each step/layer from the file. If you modify something before you install the requirements that is why it doesnt use the cache again and you should build the Dockefile based on that... but it seems you are doing it correct. Where do you build the image? BTW in docker you dont have to use virtualenv :-)